# How does one make both movement and animation to sync up and happen simultaneously?

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, movement

I am very new to Unity and game making and would appreciate if you would cope with me.

I have made a very basic prototype of character animation and movement, however trigger that is supposed to fire animation happens after character already moved. I just can't seem to find a way to fix it as `SetTrigger` is `void` and not a `Task`.

See this [video for what I mean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1yIEWycStk)

[image: animated gif]

The script I am using to fire off animation is the following:

```
public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator animator;
    public void Down()
    {
        var move = GameObject.Find("Hero").transform.position;
        animator.SetTrigger("moveDown");
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(move, move + new Vector3(0, -1f, 0), 1f); 
    }
}
```

**How does one make both movement and animation to sync up and happen simultaneously?**

Comment: Have you tried setting "moveDown" as a float? You would have the transition based off "moveDown > 0", and may need to normalise the value, before you set it; but you can also use it as a *speed multiplier*, so if you intend to move *faster*, you can make your animation move faster without much more work.

Comment: You can check for input from inside the animator script instead of setting stuff in the animator script from the input.

Comment: Little opinionated side-note: While I find the Unity animation system great for 3d animations, I think it is hopelessly overengineered for 2d games. When you just want to swap out sprites, you will have a much easier time if you just write your own. Especially when all your spritesheets are organized in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to move the character from one point to another within the single method `Down`. This is not going to work, because that whole method is executed in a single frame. `Vector3.Lerp` just by itself doesn't cause a position to change slowly. All it does is calculate a position between two positions and return that as a new vector. This is a tool which can be useful for doing a gradual transition, but just by itself it doesn't do that.

What you should do instead is have `Down` set the information that the character is walking somewhere and then do the actual position updating in `Update`.

It should look something like this (untested!):

```
public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator animator;
    private Vector3 moveDestination;
    private float moveTime = 0.0f;

    private void Start() {
         moveDestination = transform.position;
    }

    public void Down()
    {
        // when the character isn't already moving, move it down
        if (moveTime <= 0.0f) {
            moveDestination = transform.position + new Vector3(0, -1f, 0)
            moveTime = 1.0f;
            animator.SetTrigger("moveDown");
        }
    }

    public void Update() {
          if (moveTime > 0.0f) {
              moveTime -= Time.deltaTime;
              transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(moveDestination, transform.position, moveTime); 

              if (moveTime <= 0.0f) {
                  animator.SetTrigger("idle");
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Also you need to remove transition duration
Click on transition arrow in Animator window, then in Inspector window expand `Settings` under `Has Exit Time` and set both `Transition Duration` and `Transition Offset` to 0.

[image]

Comment: Hi Philipp, it worked like a charm, thanks. My animation still starts about midway through the motion though... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHrr-kOGBPo&feature=youtu.be what would be appropriate mechanism so the movement would start at same time as animation?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius This might be a problem with a too long exit time in the animation.

Comment: I have removed exit time completely from both transitions, and did return to the idle on trigger as per your example, and it still delays. Any other 'gut feelings'?

Comment: You were right I had to expand settings and change Transition Duration and Offset to 0 and this did it.